# Programming Novice-Slickdeals.net, level of programming knowledge

Tags: python

I am interested in creating a website for gardeners but in similar format to slickdeals.net, in terms of having a login page, front page, and up/down votes for comments in forum.

If I plan on using python, what how long and  how difficult will it take me to build something like this? I have never programmed before, except for a little HTML, C++.

Answer (score 1):

For such a complicated site, I'd estimate at least 6 man-months for *experienced developers* (don't forget you need to set up servers, databases, create a design etc.).

As you're apparently not experienced in website creation, you have two options:

- If it's a big project, hire one or more experienced developers (frontend/backend, system administrators, user interface experts, marketing staff, etc.).
- If you want to create it by yourself, just start with a very small feature set and keep adding new features. If your site includes attracts a community, you should be open to suggestions and code improvements. A good way to allow for that is to open-source the website's code, for example at [github](http://github.com).